# WRITE_TRUNCATE in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Am trying to truncate the table in Bigquery using `write_truncate`, but it is not happening, instead it working like `write_append`. It's appending data but not truncating the table.

Can someone please help to resolve the issue.

My code:

```
        with beam.Pipeline(options=Pipeline options()) as p:
           read=(p|"Read BQ">>beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(
    query='select empid from'\'`PRoject_Id.data_set.emp_details`',
use_standard_sql=True))|"process">>beam.Map(lambda ele:{'EMPID':ele['EMPID']})|
        "Write">>beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
    'PROJECT_ID:data_set.emp_out',
    schema='EMPID:STRING',
    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
create_dispositiom=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEDED))
        if __name__="__main__":
          run().wait_until_finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Streaming Pipelines WRITE_TRUNCATE is not supported as documented [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.20.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery).

```
For streaming pipelines WriteTruncate can not be used.
```

You can convert your pipeline to Batch and use WRITE_TRUNCATE option. To convert the Write to batch you can set `method` parameter to `FILE_LOADS`. Default this parameter is set to `STREAMING_INSERTS`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.Am using source as Bigquery which is batch load as per my knowledge.Am not using any kind of streaming here .correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Now ,the table is getting truncated but new rows are not getting added.The table is empty.Code used is:beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table_details,schema='EMPID:STRING,ENAME: STRING', write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE, create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)